# Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, startx

I get this error when running 'startx'. What is this 'nv' module, and how do I stop Xorg from trying to load it?

EDIT: I am going to try to blacklist the module 'nv' using the kernel command line. I'll update this post if that works.

I installed the Nvidia drivers, nouveau drivers and intel drivers. I also added the Nvidia drivers to /etc/mkinitcpio.conf (in MODULES). I'm on the latest version of Arch Linux.

What I tried:

- Created the xorg.conf file using nvidia-xconfig. On doing 'startx', nothing happens until I type 'exit'
- Deleted the xorg.conf file. It yields the nv module error

Also, is there a way to use the intel drivers instead of the nvidia drivers? I'd like to use this as a last resort.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/q/90915 Do you have a Nvidia graphics card? Maybe you have to install a (non-free) driver for this.

Comment: @Bodo Yes, I have an Nvidia graphics card. I installed Arch Linux before, with the Nvidia drivers and KDE and it worked. And now I'm reinstalling Arch Linux, but this time with XFCE, and it doesn't work (i.e. gives that error).

Comment: Please add this information to your question. Did you install Nvidia drivers? Did you install the new system on the same hardware? Did you install a new version of Arch Linux?

Comment: @Bodo Done. Added that info

Comment: Do you have an `xorg.conf` file? Does it reference `nv`?

Comment: @Bodo I removed the xorg.conf file

Comment: Please add all information to the question what you have written in comments so far. Currently I don't have a solution, but for others to help you it would be better to have all background information in one place, i.e. in the question. Show everything you have tried even if it did not help.

Comment: @Bodo Updated the question

Comment: `nv` is a really really ancient X driver for nvidia. You can either find out why it is installed and uninstall is (there isn't enough information in your question to find that out), or you can write a correct `xorg.conf` file which forces use of the correct driver. Have a look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to debug errors in the `xorg.conf` file. No, you can't use the Intel drivers for your nvidia card. If you both have an integrated Intel GPU and an additional Nvidia card, you'll have to use both drivers.

Comment: On some computers/laptops, both GPUs share a single output (or even multiple outputs), and many manufacturers have their own way of implementing this, so configuring everything correctly for switching requires effort. So if you use the integrated Intel GPU by default, and have an `xorg.conf` just for the Nvidia card, your screen might remain black ("nothing happens"). First step is to do `lspci -nn` and edit your question with all the graphics cards you find in the output.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the 'nv' module wasn't really the problem at all. All I had to do was remove the unnecessary lines like 'xterm' from .xinitrc, and XFCE finally started. Sure, the error is still there, but it doesn't really do anything.